# Getting transparency to work in Java

Tags: java, graphics, transparency, affinetransform

I am trying to rotate an image in Java, but when I do the transparency in the png goes away. Is there any way i can rotate the image AND keep the transparency?

> ```
>           AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();
>           trans.setTransform(identity);
>           trans.translate(100, 100);
>           trans.rotate( Math.toRadians(45) );
>
>           gr.drawImage(image.getImage(), trans, this);
> ```

This makes the transparency in the png black, but

> ```
>           gr.drawImage(image.getImage(), 0, 200, null);
> ```

Has no problem with the transparency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set rendering hints on `Graphics2D` object.

```
gr.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY );
```

Check [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html) for optimal settings.

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson you haven't any chances for up_vote in BugParade because, from my channel not possible Log_On, for example to the OTN only sometimes, another reason for why these Forums died ???

Comment: @mKorbel  Hopefully people can still lodge new bugs!  Pity about the forums.